# Is it possible to start multiple docker daemons on the same machine

Tags: docker

And if it is possible, how would you configure each daemon - graph  location, images location, etc?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to run two Docker daemons on a single host even without Docker Machine.  As of Docker 18.09.0-ce, the following `dockerd` flags are the ones that could cause conflicts if two daemons used the defaults:

```
  -b, --bridge string       Attach containers to a network bridge
      --exec-root string    Root directory for execution state files (default "/var/run/docker")
      --data-root string    Root directory of persistent Docker state (default "/var/lib/docker")
  -H, --host list           Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -p, --pidfile string      Path to use for daemon PID file (default "/var/run/docker.pid")
```

- The default for `--bridge` is `docker0`, and if you're not using the default, you must create and configure the bridge manually (Docker won't create/manage it for you).  More details below.
- `--exec-root` is where container state is stored (default: `/var/run/docker`).
- `--data-root` is where images are stored (default: `/var/lib/docker`).
- `--host` specifies where the Docker daemon will listen for client connections.  If unspecified, it defaults to `/var/run/docker.sock`.
- `--pidfile` is where the process ID of the daemon is stored (default: `/var/run/docker.pid`).

So, as long as your two daemons use different values for these flags, you can run them on the same host.  Example script (including network setup):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
## name: altdocker.sh
set -e -x

: ${bridge=altdocker}
: ${base=$HOME/$bridge}

# Set up bridge network:
if ! ip link show $bridge > /dev/null 2>&1
then
   sudo ip link add name $bridge type bridge
   sudo ip addr add ${net:-"10.20.30.1/24"} dev $bridge
   sudo ip link set dev $bridge up
fi

sudo dockerd \
  --bridge=$bridge \
  --data-root=$base.data \
  --exec-root=$base.exec \
  --host=unix://$base.socket \
  --pidfile=$base.pid
```

Example usage:

```sh
## in one terminal
$ env net=10.9.8.7/24 /bin/sh altdocker.sh
# ... log output ...

## in another terminal
$ docker -H unix://$HOME/altdocker.socket run --rm -i -t alpine sh
/ # echo hereiam
hereiam
```

---

Updated for changes from Docker 1.9.1 to 18.09.0-ce, in case anyone is using a very old version:

```
┌───────────────┬─────────────┐
│ 1.9.1         │ 18.09.0-ce  │
├───────────────┼─────────────┤
│ docker daemon │ dockerd     │
│ -g / --graph  │ --exec-root │
└───────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: This works really great. However your command to test the setup can't work the way you put it. `docker -H unix://$HOME/altdocker --rm -it alpine sh` should be `docker -H unix://$HOME/altdocker.socket run --rm -it alpine sh`.

Comment: Thanks @dynamic_cast. Extracted this from a larger script. Corrected the example.

Comment: I think --graph is called --data-root nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @SteffanKarger -- finally updated (along w/ other changes since 1.9.1, e.g. `docker daemon` -> `dockerd`).

Comment: thanks! small note to drop the dependency on `brctl`: can be replaced with `sudo ip link add name $bridge type bridge`.

Comment: Thanks @TheDiveO -- even the `brctl(8)` man page contains: `NOTES brctl(8) is obsolete. ... Instead use bridge command from iproute2 package ...` (added in October 2016).

Comment: I'm using this configuration with docker swarms. But the containers cannot see each other in the same swarm. Do you know what's going on or how to solve it?

Comment: FYI newer docker versions you can use `docker context create` to setup the client connection and `docker context use` to use it. Check the docs for more info  https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#client

Answer (score 8):

Great question! It is possible to start a Docker daemon inside a container. In that container you would be able to start more containers. This way you can run docker daemons with different settings on the same host machine.

Checkout this project: https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind. It provides a Docker image that contains Docker itself, just as you require.

Comment: It should be noted DIND (docker in docker) is something you do as a last resort or only for dev purposes. Running a container inside a container has a ton of issues. https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is doable by using [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)

Using this you can create multiple docker daemons and switch between them as you want.

Comment: How exactly would you go about doing this? You'll have to create a VM for each docker engine you want, right?

Comment: Maybe -1 because: while Docker machine manages Docker engines in remote machines and local VMs, its usecase is a single Docker engine per remote host and VM. The question especially asks for running multiple Docker engine instances in the same host, and since it specifically asks for configuring certain properties so that these instances can coexist in the same host/VM it thus did not ask for multiple VMs and thus it did not ask for Docker Machine. It's just a guess as we don't know the downvoter's motives.

Comment: Nobody supports Docker-Machine, and its source repo is archived.