# How can i lock docker container ?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine

Yesterday suddenly my containers vanished from my machine. I knew some of the my mates have done something in machine. In any case, I don't want this to happen again. 
Even, I have gone through few forums to resolve this issue and seen people mentioned about **"docker lock contianer_id"** but its not working as they mentioned. Hence, i like to know exact command or the way to protect my containers from accidental deletion. Please assist me

Comment: Did they disappear or did they just die?

Comment: disappeared completely.. no data if i do "docker ps -a"

Comment: Do the other users have superuser access (sudo etc)?

Comment: yeah they have but case here is not about access investigation. I like to lock container and image. Once i lock, nobody can delete it unknowingly. even if they try it show error. I gone through below link but its not working https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9878

Comment: Ok, so like you've seen, that issue is still open so you're probably going to have to wait until/if they implement some kind of 'important' flag for containers/volumes. You could try running your own daemon or multiple daemons: https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2018/Feb/25/multiple-docker/

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334167/is-it-possible-to-start-multiple-docker-daemons-on-the-same-machine

Comment: Right.. i wait for it anyway thanks for your links. it might help me for further improvements.

Comment: I'd go with running another docker daemon and setting up your environment variables to point to the custom socket, at least then nobody will 'accidentally' delete them. They could still do it maliciously.

Comment: yet to try these advance concept..

Comment: @byrnedo, Is there any documents to refer?