# Running gitlab-runner with multiple docker daemons

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to have several gitlab runners using different docker daemons on the same host

Currently using gitlab-runner 10.7.0 and docker 19.03.3. The goal is to maximize the usage of resources. Since I have two SSD disks on the machine, I want the runners to use both of them. The only way I found to have some runners use one disk while some others use the other disk is to have two docker daemons, one running on each disk.

I have one docker daemon running on `unix:///var/run/docker-1.sock` and one on `unix:///var/run/docker-2.sock`. They use each a dedicated bridge created manually. The (systemd) startup command line looks like `/usr/bin/dockerd --host unix:///var/run/docker_socket/docker-%i.sock --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pidfile /var/run/docker-%i.pid --data-root /data/local%i/docker/ --exec-root /data/local%i/docker_run/ --bridge docker-%i --fixed-cidr  172.%i0.0.1/17`

The `gitlab_runner` mounts `/var/run/docker_socket/` and runs on docker-1.sock.
I tried having one per docker daemon but then two jobs runs on the same runner although the limit is set to 1 (and also there are some sometimes errors appearing like `ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error: No such container: ...`)

After registration the config.toml looks like:

```
concurrent = 20
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "[...]-large"
  limit = 1
  output_limit = 32768
  url = "[...]"
  token = "[...]"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "unix:///var/run/docker-1.sock"
    tls_verify = false
    image = "debian:jessie"
    memory = "24g"
    cpuset_cpus = "1-15"
    privileged = false
    security_opt = ["seccomp=unconfined"]
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker-1.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]


[[runners]]
  name = "[...]-medium-1"
  limit = 1
  output_limit = 32768
  url = "[...]"
  token = "[...]"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "unix:///var/run/docker-2.sock"
    tls_verify = false
    image = "debian:jessie"
    memory = "12g"
    cpuset_cpus = "20-29"
    privileged = false
    security_opt = ["seccomp=unconfined"]
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker-2.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

The two docker daemons are working fine. Tested with `docker --host unix:///var/run/docker-<id>.sock ps`

The current solution seems to be kind of OK but there are random errors in the gitlab_runner logs:
`ERROR: Appending trace to coordinator... error couldn't execute PATCH against http://[...]/api/v4/jobs/223116/trace: Patch http://[...]/api/v4/jobs/223116/trace: read tcp [...] read: connection reset by peer  runner=0ec8a845`

Answer (score 0):

Other people tried this, apparently with some success:

- This one seems to list the whole set of options needed to properly run each instance of dockerd : [Is it possible to start multiple docker daemons on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334167/is-it-possible-to-start-multiple-docker-daemons-on-the-same-machine). What are yours?
- This other https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2018/Feb/25/multiple-docker/, does not speak about the possible extra bridge config.

NB: Docker documentation says the feature is *experimental*: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#run-multiple-daemons

Comment: As I said in my question, the two docker daemons are running fine. I'm using a systemd template `/lib/systemd/system/docker@.service`

Comment: And does running an executable in runner work? And not just `docker ps` ?
i.e. `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-2.sock exec [...]-medium-1 ls` ?